# Получение текста из TextBox в потоке

Tags: c#, get, text, combobox, textbox

Работаю с xNet, возникла проблема. Нужно получить информацию из combobox1 + textbox1 в потоке. Выдает ошибку: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: Попытка доступа к элементу управления 'combobox1/textbox1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан".

```
    public void Test()
    {
        while (START)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
                    var Mparams = new RequestParams();

                    Mparams["milk"] = "sun" + comboBox1.Text + textBox1.Text;

                    string Mresponse = request.Post("Сайт", Mparams).ToString();

                    if (Mresponse.Contains("\"success\":true"))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("TRUE\n"); }));
                    }
                    else if (Mresponse.Contains("\"success\":false"))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("FALSE\n"); }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("ERROR OCCURED\n"); }));
                    }

                    var cParams = new RequestParams();
                    cParams["candy"] = "sweet" + comboBox1.Text + textBox1.Text;
                    string cResponse = request.Post("Сайт", cParams).ToString();

                    if (cResponse.Contains("\"code\":0"))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("TRUE\n"); }));
                    }
                    else if (cResponse.Contains("\"code\":1"))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("FALSE\n"); }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("ERROR OCCURED\n"); }));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Про Invoke, Delegate, BackgroundWorker, Dispatcher знаю. Но, не знаю, как правильно организовать получение данных в параметрах запроса xNet. Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Благодарю.

> Вызываю таким образом:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    START = true; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++) 
    {
        Thread sThread = new Thread(Test); 
        sThread.IsBackground = true; 
        sThread.Start(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Откуда и как вы вызываете метод `Test()` ?

Comment: @DigitalCore
Вызываю при клике на кнопку, таким образом:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            START = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
            {
                Thread sThread = new Thread(Test);
                sThread.IsBackground = true;
                sThread.Start();
            }
        }

Comment: Никто не может помочь?

Comment: Всё верно, ваш поток `sThread.IsBackground = true;` то есть фоновый, мало того текст-боксы созданы в основном UI потоке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `Delegate`,и `Invoke`

Создайте класс `Threads` добавьте в него методы.

```
public class Threads
{
    private ChangeUI _ui;

    private List<Thread> _threads;

    public Threads(ChangeUI ui)
    {
        _ui = ui;
    }

    public void Run(int countThreads)
    {
        _threads = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < countThreads; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(Test);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            _threads.Add(thread);
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
        {
            thread.Abort();
        }

        _threads.Clear();
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        // любые действия
        _ui("здесь то что нужно передать в форму")
    }
}
```

В форме создайте делегат:

```
public delegate void ChangeUI(string s);
```

инициализируйте

```
private ChangeUI myUi;
private Threads _myThreads;
```

метод

```
public void Changed(string s)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(myUi, s);
        return;
    }
    // Здесь любые действия с элементами управления
}
```

Вызываем метод из класса `Threads`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    myUi = new ChangeUI(Changed);
    _myThreads = new Threads(myUi);
    _myThreads.Run(5);     
}
```

Материал исключительно в ознакомительных целях, использовать код без правок в проектах не рекомендую, используйте асинхронные методы.

Если материал вам помог, проголосуйте за него.